# Existe diferença entre as plataformas Java?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, mobile, aplicação-desktop

Em:

- Java Desktop
- Java Mobile
- Java Web

As linguagens são diferentes, ou é padrão mudando apenas o ambiente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linguagem é a mesma, o que muda é o entorno dela, as bibliotecas extras (as básicas são as mesmas). Agora, quando fala em mobile, talvez esteja falando de Android, aí tem que tomar um pouco de cuidado porque nessa plataforma a implementação costuma estar atrasada e não ter tudo que está disponível nas versões mais novas da linguagem, tem que sempre verificar o que já pode usar. Se a linguagem mudar fora do padrão, não pode usar o nome Java.

A coisa é um pouco mais complicada. Hoje existem diversas implementações da plataforma onde o Java roda.

Comment: Obrigado. Bem direto e bem explicado.